# Remove unnecessary blank lines

Tags: bash, shell

Let's imagine that the following code example is valid:

```
begin
   statement1;

   begin


      statement2;

      statement3;
      statement4;

      statement5;

   end;

   statement6;

end;
```

I would like to remove all unnecessary blank lines in this code example:

```
begin
   statement1;

   begin
      statement2;

      statement3;
      statement4;

      statement5;
   end;

   statement6;
end;
```

So basically if a line ends with the keyword `begin` then all blank lines until the next line that contains a statement should be removed and if a line ends with the keyword `end;` then all blank lines until the previous  line that contains a statement should be removed.

Using Sublime Text I created two regular expressions:

1. Find: `begin(\n)*` and Replace: `begin\n`
2. Find: `(\n)*([[:space:]])*end;` and Replace: `\nend;`

My questions:

1. How can I convert both regular expression so that they can be used with `sed` (in-place)?
2. The second regular expression drops all existing blank spaces before the keyword `end;`. How could this problem be fixed?

Comment: `sed` operates one line at a time, you can't use a regexp to match across multiple lines.

Comment: `awk` would probably be a better tool for this.

Comment: @Barmar Can you explain why Walter A answer using sed is working?

Comment: He's tricking it by turning the entire file into one long line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed 4.2 you have the option `-z`:

```
sed -rz 's/begin\n+/begin\n/g;s/\n+([^\n]*end;)/\n\1/g' file
```

Work-around with older `sed` (when original file is without `\r`)

```
tr '\n' '\r' < file | sed -r 's/begin\r+/begin\r/g;s/\r+([^\r]*end;)/\r\1/g' | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the moment only `end;` is recognized by the regular expression. What do I need to change that also for example `end Hello;` or `end Hello_Foo_Bar` is handled correctly?

Comment: Why is `end Hello;` not working now? Because `sed` looks for `end;`, nothing between `end`and `;`. You can allow more with `end[^;\n];` (GNU 4.2) or `end[^;\r];`. Be aware that `[^\n]*end` also matches `friend`, so yo might want something like `[^\n\s]*end`.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but I'll continue trying this one :)

```
cat file | awk '
length { print; b=0 }
/begin/ { b=1 }
/^$/ && b { next }
!length && !b { print }
' | tac | awk '
length { print; b=0 }
/end;/ { b=1 }
/^$/ && b { next }
!length && !b { print }
' | tac
```

I'm running the same `awk`, but I invert the file for the `end;` part (`tac`).

Explanation of the `awk`:

1. If the line is not empty (`length`), print it and set `b` to `0` (false)
2. If the line starts with the string `begin` (ignoring blank chars [`\s`]), set `b` to `1` (true)
3. If the line is blank (`^$`), and `b` is true (we're 1 line after `begin`), skip this line (`next`)
4. If the line is blank and we're not after `begin`, print (because we don't want to eliminate all blank lines)